# What is diffrence between h1.class and h1(space).class

Tags: javascript

Can you describe  what is difference between `h1.test` and `h1(space).test` .... I'm having problem when two selectors are called together and also a selector inside a selector in JavaScript

Comment: there shouldn't be any difference. Show us some code to highlight the problems that you are having.

Answer (score 2):

> [Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)
>
> E.warning an E element whose class is "warning" (the document language
>   specifies how class is determined). [Class selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html)
>
> E F   an F element descendant of an E element [Descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

`h1.class` selects `<h1>` elements having `.className` `"class"`.

`h1 .class` selects child elements of `<h1>` having `.className` `"class"`.

Answer (score 0):

h1.class -- refers to <h1> tag with class named "class"
h1(space).class -- refers to all the element(s) having class named "class" inside the <h1> tag.